# Spring Boot Unable to Locate `javax.servlet.Filter` Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have an issue with getting my Java Spring Boot application to run. I get the error message below. I believe I have all of the necessary dependencies. However, the error seems to be in correlation to the `javax.servlet.Filter` class, which I have on my pom.xml file, but unless I have a deprecated version, I am not sure where my issue is located... After investigating further, the issue seems to be that I am using Spring Security in my project, and Spring Security is trying to create a HttpSecurity object to configure security filters, but it's unable to find the necessary `javax.servlet.Filter` class. My project is running Java 17.

Error Message:

```
/Users/jonathandameus/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-21.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=64529:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/jonathandameus/Code_GitHub/JDT_Client/JR_Property_Management/server/JRPropertyManagement/target/classes:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-aop-3.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.20/aspectjweaver-1.9.20.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/5.0.1/HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/6.0.13/spring-jdbc-6.0.13.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.2.13.Final/hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/3.1.0/jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/jakarta/transaction/jakarta.transaction-api/2.0.1/jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.5.3.Final/jboss-logging-3.5.3.Final.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/6.0.6.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/jandex/3.0.5/jandex-3.0.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.14.9/byte-buddy-1.14.9.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/4.0.3/jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/4.0.3/jaxb-core-4.0.3.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/angus/angus-activation/2.0.1/angus-activation-2.0.1.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/4.0.3/txw2-4.0.3.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/4.1.2/istack-commons-runtime-4.1.2.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/jakarta/inject/jakarta.inject-api/2.0.1/jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.10.1/antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/3.1.5/spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/3.1.5/spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/6.0.13/spring-orm-6.0.13.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/6.0.13/spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/2.1.1/jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.9/slf4j-api-2.0.9.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/6.0.13/spring-aspects-6.0.13.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-web-3.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-3.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.1.5/spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.1.5/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-logging-3.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.4.11/logback-classic-1.4.11.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.4.11/logback-core-1.4.11.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.20.0/log4j-to-slf4j-2.20.0.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.20.0/log4j-api-2.20.0.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/2.0.9/jul-to-slf4j-2.0.9.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.33/snakeyaml-1.33.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-json-3.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.15.3/jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.15.3/jackson-annotations-2.15.3.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.15.3/jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.15.3/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.3.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.15.3/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.3.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.15.3/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.3.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/10.1.15/tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/10.1.15/tomcat-embed-el-10.1.15.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/10.1.15/tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.15.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.13/spring-web-6.0.13.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-observation/1.11.5/micrometer-observation-1.11.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-commons/1.11.5/micrometer-commons-1.11.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/6.0.13/spring-webmvc-6.0.13.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/8.0.33/mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.1/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.1.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.1.2/jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.13/spring-core-6.0.13.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/6.0.13/spring-jcl-6.0.13.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/5.7.7/spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/6.0.13/spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/6.0.13/spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.13/spring-context-6.0.13.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/6.0.13/spring-expression-6.0.13.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/5.5.8/spring-security-core-5.5.8.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/6.1.5/spring-security-crypto-6.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-security-3.1.5.jar:/Users/jonathandameus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/6.1.5/spring-security-config-6.1.5.jar com.jondoetech.JRPropertyManagement.JrPropertyManagementApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.5)

2023-11-09T01:54:07.216-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] c.j.J.JrPropertyManagementApplication    : Starting JrPropertyManagementApplication using Java 21.0.1 with PID 64162 (/Users/jonathandameus/Code_GitHub/JDT_Client/JR_Property_Management/server/JRPropertyManagement/target/classes started by jonathandameus in /Users/jonathandameus/Code_GitHub/JDT_Client/JR_Property_Management/server/JRPropertyManagement)
2023-11-09T01:54:07.219-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] c.j.J.JrPropertyManagementApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-11-09T01:54:07.873-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-11-09T01:54:07.928-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 49 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-11-09T01:54:08.460-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-11-09T01:54:08.470-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-11-09T01:54:08.471-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.15]
2023-11-09T01:54:08.561-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-11-09T01:54:08.562-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1286 ms
2023-11-09T01:54:08.731-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-11-09T01:54:08.774-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.13.Final
2023-11-09T01:54:08.776-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-11-09T01:54:08.977-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-11-09T01:54:08.997-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-11-09T01:54:09.318-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@36463b09
2023-11-09T01:54:09.321-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-11-09T01:54:09.982-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2023-11-09T01:54:10.012-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-11-09T01:54:10.367-05:00  WARN 64162 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-11-09T01:54:10.395-05:00  WARN 64162 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'httpSecurity': Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception with message: javax/servlet/Filter
2023-11-09T01:54:10.396-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-11-09T01:54:10.398-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-11-09T01:54:10.405-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-11-09T01:54:10.406-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-11-09T01:54:10.415-05:00  INFO 64162 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-11-09T01:54:10.435-05:00 ERROR 64162 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'httpSecurity': Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception with message: javax/servlet/Filter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:492) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.jondoetech.JRPropertyManagement.JrPropertyManagementApplication.main(JrPropertyManagementApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception with message: javax/servlet/Filter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:654) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:488) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:343) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:764) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception with message: javax/servlet/Filter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.FilterOrderRegistration.<init>(FilterOrderRegistration.java:117) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.<init>(HttpSecurity.java:158) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity(HttpSecurityConfiguration.java:110) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
    ... 47 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jondoetech</groupId>
    <artifactId>JRPropertyManagement</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JRPropertyManagement</name>
    <description>JRPropertyManagement using Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version> <!-- Use a more recent version -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: springboot3 javax ==> jakarta

Comment: Spring Boot 3.x requires Spring Security 6.x (because of the change from Java EE with `javax.servlet` classes to Jakarta EE with `jakarta.servlet` classes)

Comment: So you are saying to change spring-security-web and spring-security-core to version 6.x if available and my issue should be resolved?

Comment: Drop all explicit versions of Spring (Boot) dependencies - those are provided by the Spring Boot parent. You're now running into possible version mismatches. Also prefer to use starters; `spring-boot-starter-security` should be sufficient for both. Drop the explicit servlet API dependency - you're getting the correct dependency (jakarta) through `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the filter is in `jakarta.servlet.Filter` (not in `javax.servlet.Filter`), since Java 17. However, the 5.x.x Spring Security is still relying on `javax.servlet.Filter`, so you must either downgrade your Spring Boot version to use Java8, or upgrade your Spring Security version to 6.x.x.

Comment: I took your advice, and it instantly worked! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In the java 17 ,all the packages that were located under javax.servlet have been replaced with jakarta.servlet.

so  all the packages and classes that were once part of javax.servlet (e.g., javax.servlet.Servlet, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, etc.) have been moved to the jakarta.servlet namespace (e.g., jakarta.servlet.Servlet, jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, etc.)

Change your dependency accordingly to make it work

Comment: Your explanation contributed to getting my issue resolved! Thanks!